# How to navigate inside helm buffer

Tags: helm

How to navigate inside helm (helm-mini in this case) **vertically with arrow keys**? I mean, I wanna go to `Recentf` "submenu" (like on picture), but pressing down arrow keep iterating over `Buffers`. I found a way to use PageUp/PageDown, but this is quite inconvenient. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Try press `CTRL+o`, it should make focus switch to the next source.